# jStyleParser can't parse my html file

Tags: java, css, parsing, dom, jstyleparser

I'm trying to use the jStyleParser library ( part of the CSSBox project) to analyze the css of a generic web page and bind all the css information to the DOM of that page.
My goal is, given a web page,  to have a DOM tree such that, for each node, I can get all the css informations realted to tha node.

This is (part of) my code:

```
System.out.println("Analizing "+Mylocalfile.getAbsolutePath()); 
StyleSheet ss = CSSFactory.parse(Mylocalfile.getAbsolutePath(), "UTF-8");
if (ss.isEmpty()) System.out.println("StyleSheet is void");
```

The parse method seem to be unable to parse the file: the StyleSheet ss is infact void.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct as long as *MyLocalFile* points to a CSS style sheet (*.css). In that case, you should obtain the parsed style sheet in *ss* but it is not bound to any DOM. If you still obtain an empty style sheet, there might be a bug in the CSS code or even in the parser. In that case, I recommend to report this to the [jStyleParser forum at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssbox/).

If you want to assign the style definitions to a DOM (*MyLocalFile* points to an HTML file), you should use the *assignDOM* method as described in the [jStyleParser manual](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/manual.php). In that case, you should parse the HTML document with a DOM parser and use the *assignDOM* method to automatically retrieve the referenced style sheets and compute the element styles. You may find an example in src/test/DOMAssign.java in the jStyleParser source package.

Comment: Thank you Radkovo, few ours ago I wrote on jStyleParser's forum about the ambiguos documentation: just after sever testing I understood that Mylocalfile should be an Css file and not an htmlf file, and that was my duty to extract all the ccs urls from the <link> tags inside the html code.

Comment: Now I'm facing new issuses: inside the assignDOM method is not clear what the "media" parameter rapresents. And after that, if I have an org.w3c.dom Node (part of the assigned DOM), how i can get its style definitions?